# I want to add Call to Action Button under Slider in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi I am new to wordpress thats why I am facing some issues in it. 
One of them is when I add Call to Action Button Element using WPBakery Page Builder and preview my change then the content in preview is removed from the page but when I remove the Call to Action Button Element from page the preview loads all content again

[Page without Call to Action Button Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3vIq.png)

When I preview the above page I get all my content in Preview as below

[Preview without Call to Action Button Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwA7x.jpg)

But the problem occurs when I add Call to Action Button

[Page after adding Call to Action Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miwwr.png)

When I preview after adding element I get following preview

[Preview after adding Call to Action Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCV7H.png)

Here is the video link of this

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WUjtVePoL2BYTE5q4UublMRt1LaK48CK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you try to add the call to action button to a seperate test page and see what happens if there is only call to action button on that page as content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Soliloquy Slider Plugin for this. Install and active the plugin then go Go to your WordPress dashboard then **Soliloquy » Add New**. Give a title of your slider and add some image for the slider to show.
You can drag and drop image from your local file directory or can browse image. After adding the images just click on the publish button.

After publishing the slider in your right side screen some code and information will appear. You will need this information later to add this slider in any pages or posts.

Install and Activate Soliloquy’s Custom CSS Addon
Add CSS to Create a Call-to-Action Button
Add HTML for Call-to-Action Button

You can follow this [tutorial](https://niamrox.com/how-to-add-call-to-action-button-under-slider-in-wordpress/) for in depth explanation